# WCF Rest Service not taking "#" with parameter

Tags: rest, wcf

I have created a WCF Rest service in .NET. It is not taking # character with parameter. Example: http://localhost:7375/service1.svc/getuser/admin@echo.com/abc@123#.

If I am passing "abc@123#" as parameter, service treats it as "abc@123". what is wrong here? If I am missing any settings?

Comment: You need to encode the '#' symbol. The default encoding for '#' is %23 - .NET has URL encoding methods might be worth looking into those.